# mongodb find().sort().exec(fn) Returns the number of the document?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a collection in mongodb with around 1600 documents and I am trying to retrieve all the data from it using the following query:

`db.collection.find().sort({team:1}).exec(fn)`

The problem is that it only returns **1000** documents? Does anyone have an idea of why my last **600** documents are not being retrieved?

Comment: Please write some more about your issue. Less details...

Comment: I want to return more than 1000 the document